# How to know which layer is active in a certain 3d view

Tags: python

I have couple of 3d views in my file, where all of them has layer 0 as the active layer and only one of them has layer 1 as the active layer. I wonder how I can check which layer is active in a 3d view, like in my case I want to know which 3dview has layer 1 active in it.

This is what I did so far:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        if area.spaces.active.layers_used[1] == True: # <-- not working if other 3d views has layer 1 even if it's not active in this 3dview

            #do something
```

like the one shown below:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by active, that its visible? the layer used when adding new objects?

Comment: @ideasman42 yes, the visible selected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [SpaceView3D.layers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=view3d#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.layers) attribute.

`layers_used` is for the layers that have content (as shown by the *dots)*